# How to use bazel query to get all test rule types in BUILD file?

Tags: bazel

A bazel query like `bazel query 'kind(".*_test", //path/to/package:*)'` will give the names of all test rules in the BUILD file.
But how would one get the actual test rule types in the BUILD file? i.e., **py_test**, **cc_test**, ...  find out which of these types of rules existed/

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `--output label_kind` flag, e.g.:

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query-how-to.html#what-rules-are-defined-in-the-foo-package

Comment: What bazel version is this supposed to work with? With 0.29.1 I get: `ERROR: Invalid output format 'label_kind'. Valid values are: label, transitions, proto, textproto, build`

Comment: Are you using `cquery`? `label_kind` only works with `query`

Comment: Ah yes that's it. What's the reasoning behind making the output format dependend on the query type? As far as I know, the only difference between `query` and `cquery` is that the former follows all paths, whereas the latter only follows the path specified by the `--config` argument... thus the general types of query results (and the output filtering) should be the same.

Comment: I'm not aware of a specific reason that `label_kind` isn't supported with `cquery`. I filed https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/10574 (also, just to elaborate, `cquery` operates on the configured target graph, which includes the results of evaluating `selects()`, which uses configuration information, which comes (mostly) from flags, which can be set with `--config` :) )